# Trying to understand a theorem of Chow

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

What is an example of a compact analytic subspace of the complex manifold $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{C}}^n$, the projective $n$-space over $\mathbf{C}$? Are they classified?

Comment: They are all algebraic, that is, they are all defined by the zero sets of a finite set of polynomials.

Comment: Beyond the statement of Chow's theorem it's not clear what you're expecting. I don't think we even know which curves are "allowed" for $n > 5$.